How to put cap line of text on path? (In inkscape)
When selecting text and a path like a circle, you can put the text on the circle using text>put on path. However, this wraps the baseline of the text to the circle. How can I wrap the cap line of the text instead? This would prevent the bunching of the text at the bottom of a circle when doing text>put on path & flip vertical.
EDIT: I mean is there a function that puts the cap line on the path the same way it puts the baseline on the path. I'm sure that I could do it manually with quite some imprecision. Or I could calculate exact values in a spreadsheet and then manually position and rotate each letter.


You can offset selected text perpendicular to the path by holding Alt and pressing the up or down arrow-keys. If needed, you can then use Alt + < or Alt + > (less than/greater than keys) to change letter spacing.
Alternatively, you can enter precise values into the inputs inside the 'Spacing' popover in the toolbar.

One other thing you can do is manually adding the dominant-baseline attribute to the text element using the 'Edit → XML Editor...' with a value of text-before-edge, which is, however, based on the top of the em-square, not the cap height.


I should say that I want to put the cap line on a path programmatically. I'm not good with inexact operations.

@SvenVoigt The cap height is highly font dependent, I'm not even sure all fonts store that information. The SVG spec doesn't even mention cap-height in relation to text elements at all. The best you can do is the top of the em-square. I've updated my answer to show how.

that works pretty well. Do you know if there is an exact offset value that can be given? I can measure the font height.

Ok, I did middle as the baseline for the top and bottom and that seems to have given the same spacing to both.

To give additional context for others searching this:
Fonts specify a different spacing between all pairs of characters, which is called kerning, and is designed to provide a visually pleasing (or similar looking) distance between any two characters. However, this spacing is affected by bending. When there are letters on the concave side of a bend, there is potential for overlap. Additionally, due to kerning, a positive or negative bend will look visually different, even if the bend is the same radius and the characters have the same spacing. That is why I believe @Xrott at first recommended I manually adjust spacing. However, it seems that manual spacing in inkscape is uniformly applied and it does not get into the nuances of specifying pairwise spacing between two characters. That's why I don't even want to get into it unless I were to design my own font that is designed to arch or bend at a particular radius in a positive or negative direction. Therefore, I believe applying the same transformation on the text for a positive or negative bend is optimal.
The solution @Xrott specified of adjusting the dominant-baseline is a great solution, but still doesn't exactly match bending around the cap line. Therefore, if I measure the height of the text and then create two circles of radius x and x+height, the negative arch on the inside of the x+height circle would still cause a different spacing between characters. Instead, I found that bending around the middle line of two circles with radius x produced spacing in positive and negative bending text that was about the same. However, I still had to adjust the final text somewhat by stretching in the x direction because I had a Capital to under baseline word, like Jag. So the J seemed much higher than the g.
For reference, other dominant-baseline attributes can be found on mozilla's page.
